# How to rebind Super key to a command?

Tags: emacs

How can I rebind the Super key itself to a command? It seems like the key has to be the prefix of something.

I am using Emacs 24.3 and with Prelude. I disabled the Super key combos in Prelude and rebind to a command, but didn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: @lawlist I am using Ubuntu. My use case is simpler than your posted link; I simply one to bind `super` key to a certain function. BUt I guess I will try again.

Comment: Do you know how can I query all the command with super key involved?

Comment: Because the `super` key appears to be a special case scenario, I've removed my initial comments / thoughts as they were not on point.  I was not able to figure out a way to achieve the result you seek.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, because the other question has an answer which explains why this doesn't work. You *can* resolve this if you are willing to re-assign (or lose) the 'super' modifier, but that's an OS question, not an Emacs question.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, make sure <kbd>super</kbd> isn't taken by your system, windows-manager etc.

Some examples at work here:

```
(global-set-key [(control c)(super \})] 'ar-brace-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super backspace)] 'ar-kill-backward-alnum-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super +)] 'ar-add-to-number)
(global-set-key [(super -)] 'ar-decrease-number)
(global-set-key [(super S)] 'hs-show-all)
(global-set-key [(super \!)] 'scroll-other-window-down)
(global-set-key [(super \")] 'ar-doublequoted-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super \')] 'ar-singlequoted-atpt)
```

Comment: How about `[(super)]` alone? This is what I need.

Comment: @Amumu Okay, see I mistook your question. AFAIU <super> is a modifier key, as <control> and <alt>. Can't imagine you want to dig into the system that far taking this quality away.

Answer (score 0):

This **worked** for me ( Ubuntu 14.04 and Emacs 25.0);

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "s-r") 'recentf-open-files)
```

Add above code into your emacs customization file .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el and restart the emacs.

Reference : http://www.emacswiki.org/PrefixKey